# Merge a list of excel files into a new excel book

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a macro that merges a list of excel files in a directory.
The folder contains other files that I don't want to pick. So, I need to specify the list of files (such as, selecting all the files which name contains "*02.08*.xlsx").

This is my first time using VBA, so please take that into consideration.
I've tried some things, but I think I always get problems regarding the files selection.

Here's what I've tried so far, but not working:

```
Sub MergeWorkbooks()
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim ListFilenames As Variant
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FolderPath = CurDir()
ListFilenames = Array("*02.08.02.01*.xlsx", "*02.08.13.01*.xlsx")
For i = 1 To 2
    Filename = Dir(FolderPath & ListFilenames(i))
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Next Sheet
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    Filename = Dir()
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at this Excel VBA code: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2219-excel-list-all-folders-and-subfolders.html

With this you can list all files or folders on a path, and with that data you can filter wathever you want

Comment: For i = 1 To 2
is to be changed  For i = 0 To 1

Comment: @Dy.Lee Thanks. Still doesn't work. I placed a check after I define Filename, but it's always blank. Something is wrong when I define the Filename I guess.

Comment: you missed filepathseperater.  Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & "\" Filename, ReadOnly:=True

Comment: @Dy.Lee That was the problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is wouldb be like this.

```
Sub MergeWorkbooks()
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim ListFilenames As Variant
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FolderPath = CurDir()
    ListFilenames = Array("*02.08.02.01*.xlsx", "*02.08.13.01*.xlsx")
    For i = 0 To 1
        Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "\" & ListFilenames(i))
        Do While Filename <> ""
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & "\" & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
            For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            Next Sheet
            Workbooks(Filename).Close
            Filename = Dir()
        Loop
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: As stated in the comments above, the problem was the index (should start at zero) and the missing file path separator "\".

Answer (score 0):

Use the AddIn from the link below.

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

That will do what you want.